# Sklearn and cross_val_scores: can we use it for leave-one-out cross validation?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am writing a loop where I have to execute the k-fold cross-validation on 1000 entries. The value of k changes at every iteration in the loop and it can have the value of 1000. However, when trying to do the leave-on-out cross-validation (i.e. k = #entries = 1000) I receive the following error:

*ValueError: All the n_groups for individual classes are less than n_splits=1000.*

test = [...,...,1000]
for n in test:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X_train, y_train, cv=n, scoring='accuracy')
```

Remember that X_train and y_train have 1000 rows and are numpy arrays.
I know there are specific methods for the LOO but I am wondering whether there could be a way to use the same function in order to avoid inserting an if in the loop.

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using? I'm guessing it's not up to date because on the latest version this code would fail at n > `np.bincount(y_train).min() `

Comment: As per [the documentation of LOO](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) it is equivalent to `KFold(n_splits=n)`, so you are correct in that part. But as @ncfirth said, it will depend on the type of values in your `y`. Is it binary, or multi-class and if multi-class, is there a class which have only a single row? Other than that, please add a [minimal, complete, easy to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code snippet and full trace of error.